# localStorage in Nuxt js is not working in SSR mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm trying to add items in a cart using vuex but getting some error in the console and the product in the page is not showing as well. Please tell me how to solve this issue.
here is the error in console

```
client.js?06a0:103 SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Store.initializeStore (index.js?9101:14)
    at wrappedMutationHandler (vuex.esm.js?2f62:844)
    at commitIterator (vuex.esm.js?2f62:466)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (vuex.esm.js?2f62:465)
    at Store._withCommit (vuex.esm.js?2f62:624)
    at Store.commit (vuex.esm.js?2f62:464)
    at Store.boundCommit [as commit] (vuex.esm.js?2f62:409)
    at VueComponent.mounted (default.vue?ec86:82)
```

Here is the store.js where I'm trying to use localStorage

```
export const state = () => ({
    cart:{
        items:[],
    },
    isAuthenticated: false,
    token: '',
    isLoading: false,

})
  
export const mutations = {
    initializeStore(state) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
          state.cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'))
        } else {
          localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(state.cart))
        }
    },
    addToCart(state, item) {
        const exists = state.cart.items.filter(i => i.product.id === item.product.id)
        if (exists.length) {
          exists[0].quantity = parseInt(exists[0].quantity) + parseInt(item.quantity)
        } else {
          state.cart.items.push(item)
        }
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(state.cart))
    },

}

export const actions = {

}
```

Here is the default.vue where I'm trying to access localStorage from vuex

```
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      title:'QL Gadgets',
      cart:{
        items:[]
      },
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.$store.commit('initializeStore')
  },
  computed:{
    cartTotalLenght(){
      let totalLenght = 0
      for(let i=0; i < this.cart.items.length; i++){
        totalLenght += this.cart.items[i].quantity
      }
      return totalLenght
    }
  },
  methods:{
    handleClick(){
        if(this.$refs.menu.classList.contains('hidden')){
            this.$refs.menu.classList.remove('hidden')
        }
        else{
            this.$refs.menu.classList.add('hidden')
        }
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is likely that at some point you set an string in local storage that is not JSON-parseable or there is nothing in the response (`undefined` starts with `u`). Check your local storage with your chosen browser (e.g. [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/localstorage/) or [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector)) to see if this is the case.

In any event, you should handle errors reading from local storage or parsing the result. For example, the first time a user visits the page there won't be anything there and `JSON.parse` will fail. For example:

```js
export const mutations = {
  initializeStore(state) {
    try {
      state.cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'))
    } catch {
      localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(state.cart))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The server can't see into browser local storage because local storage is a feature of the client. What I think is happening is that localStorage.getItem('cart') is returning undefined and the error your seeing is from trying to JSON.parse undefined when it is expecting to find valid JSON.

Your store is firing the applicable function server-side because of the mounted hook in your template during the server render.

You will need to wait to call localStorage.getItem on the client side and then pass it back to the server (using server-miidleware for processing if requiring additional node access after load) or just process it client-side and commit the results to store.

I also find that using vuex-persistedstate is a good augmentation to this logic or alternative, you can selectively persist your cart after the first commitment and then your server can access it on later instantiations of your app.

Comment: The `mounted()` hook does not run on server side.